# strings swap in c

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void swap(char *, char *);

    int main()
    {
        char *pstr[2] = {"Hello", "IndiaBIX"};
        swap(&pstr[0],&pstr[1]);
        printf("%s\t%s", pstr[0], pstr[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    void swap(char **t1, char **t2)
    {
         char *t;
         t=*t1;
         *t1=*t2;
         *t2=*t;
    }
```

I don't understand why can't swap the pointer of strings by calling the function like this:

```
swap(pstr[0],pstr[1]);
```

I was in a dilemma why I should not use that.Some one please help me.

thanks..

Comment: Your prototype, `void swap(char *, char *);`, doesn't match the definition, that's undefined behaviour (and the compiler _should_ refuse to compile it [IMO]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you have mainly two errors:

- in the instruction `*t2 = *t`, `*t2` is a string whereas `*t` is a single character;
- the declaration of `swap` is different from its definition.

Also, `pstr[0]` and `pstr[1]` can be pointers to read-only strings, so declare them as pointers to `const char` is considered as a good practice.

In that case, the following code works fine (it swaps just the value of the both pointers, not the strings themselves).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void 
swap(const char ** const p, const char ** const q)
{
    const char * const pTmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = pTmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *p[] = { "Hello", "IndiaBIX" };
    printf("%s - %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    swap(p, p + 1);
    printf("%s - %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why can't swap the pointer of strings by calling
>   the function like this swap(pstr[0],pstr[1](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html));

Because the swap function expects a **pointer to a pointer**, not a pointer to a char. It's like that because it changes the actual pointers, not their contents. This [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) is relevant.

Comment: Once i tried to measure string copy speed and got 500M Strings /s and string length was 4096. Does it do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is mismatch in declaration and definition of the function swap. Look into it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's time for you to get acquainted with a debugger. If you're on linux, I can recommend `gdb`.

Compile your program with debug-info using the `-g` switch.

Run you program:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
```

to set a breakpoint in `main`:

```
b main
```

run program using the `r` command. Now, step through the code using `n` and look at the variables using the `p` command. Good Luck.