# String sorting alphabetically using array of pointers

Tags: c

I wish to sort the strings alphabetically using swap function. The swap function doesn't seems to work. Should i pass the entire array of strings into swap as well ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void swap (char *s, char *t);
void main()
{
    char *name[10] = {"Noida","Lucknow","Kanpur","Mohali","Chandigarh","Mumbai","Kerala","Chennai","Bangalore","Indore"};
    char *temp;
    printf("The names are :\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",name[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSORTING ALPHABETICALLY - \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name[i],name[j])>0)
                swap(name[i],name[j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",name[i]);
    }
}
void swap (char *s, char *t) //Not swapping
{
    char *temp;
              temp = s;
              s = t;
              t = temp;
}
```

Comment: You are swapping the function arguments, not what they point to. These are *copies* of what you passed, which are then forgotten.

Comment: So how to make this change reflect in the main() ?

Comment: I suggest the function should take the array (pointer), and the indices of the two elements to be swapped, or, as one answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strings swap in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214309/strings-swap-in-c)

Comment: Instead of writing your own sorting code you should use `qsort`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the pointers by copy. The function operates on its own local variables which are copies of the pointers to those strings, not the pointers to the `main` variables. So it can change the strings but not those variables(= values of those pointers). This should fix it:

```
void swap (char **s, char **t) 
{
    char *temp;
    temp = *s;
    *s = *t;
    *t = temp;
}
```

Edit: As stated in the comment bellow: Then call it like  `swap(&name[i],&name[j]);`

Comment: And of course changing the function call to `swap(&name[i], &name[j]);`.

Comment: @Blaze or just `swap( name+i, name+j );`